# How to add entry for CA certificate in LDAP without authorityRevocationList?

Tags: java, ldap

I am trying to add a entry for CA certificate without `authorityRevocationList`.
But i get this error:

> *javax.naming.directory.SchemaViolationException: [LDAP: error code 65 - object class 'certificationAuthority' requires attribute 'authorityRevocationList']*

But as far as i Know `authorityRevocationList` attribute is not **mandatory**.

Here is my code:

```
    FileInputStream fr = new FileInputStream("jack.cer");
    CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X509");
    X509Certificate crt = (X509Certificate) cf.generateCertificate(fr);

    Attribute oc = new BasicAttribute("objectClass");
    oc.add("person");
    oc.add("inetOrgPerson");
    oc.add("certificationAuthority");
    Attributes entry = new BasicAttributes();
    String entryDN=""Cn=test,dc=maxcrc,dc=com";
    entry.put("sn", entryDN);
    entry.put("cACertificate;binary", crt.getEncoded());
    entry.put(oc);
    try {
        ctx.createSubcontext(entryDN, entry);
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The error message is telling you you're wrong and that authorityRevocationList is mandatory for the certificationAuthority object class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by using pkiCA object class instead of certificationAuthority object class.Here is the working code.

```
FileInputStream fr = new FileInputStream("jack.cer");
CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X509");
X509Certificate crt = (X509Certificate) cf.generateCertificate(fr);

Attribute oc = new BasicAttribute("objectClass");
oc.add("person");
oc.add("inetOrgPerson");
oc.add("pkiCA");
Attributes entry = new BasicAttributes();
String entryDN=""Cn=test,dc=maxcrc,dc=com";
entry.put("sn", entryDN);
entry.put("cACertificate;binary", crt.getEncoded());
entry.put(oc);
try {
    ctx.createSubcontext(entryDN, entry);
} catch (NamingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```